# Jquery Form submit with bootstrap modal confirmation

Tags: jquery, validation, modal-dialog

I have a form (Bootstarp3) with jquery form validation plugin. Now I want to submit the form after validating the form and when I submit the form, I want modal to confirm the form submit. How can I do that?

Do I need to put the modal within submit handler?

```
$("#dischargeform").validate({ submitHandle : { ??? } }).
```

Comment: what did you try ? show us some code to help

Comment: $("dischargeform").validate({ submitHandle : { ??? } }). Do I need to put the modal within submit handler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is unclear;

> *when I submit the form, I want modal to confirm the form submit.*

If you want to show the modal after the form submit then you need to submit the form with Ajax otherwise once the form submitted after validation there is no possible way to show a modal window **but** if you are looking to show the modal after form validation but before form submission, following solution will work.

This is how you can show confirmation BS Modal after validating form inputs and submit `form` from confirmation BS Modal. Required libraries are

- Bootstrap
- jQuery Form Validation

HTML Form

```
<form action="" id="dischargeform" method="post" name="" class="">
        <p>
            <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" class="form-control">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
            <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" class="form-control">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Bootstrap Modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel3" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                 <h3 id="myModalLabel3">Confirmation Heading</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are You Sure You want To submit The Form</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close This Modal</button>
                <button class="btn-primary btn" id="SubForm">Confirm and Submit The Form</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Validation

Yes you have to put the modal within submit handler.

```
$("#dischargeform").validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: "required",
        lastname: "required",
    },
    messages: {
        firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
        lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
        $('#SubForm').click(function () {
            form.submit();
       });
    }
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/evuoo2py/1/)

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. But you gave me the exact answer what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: You are most welcome, you forget to mark the answer correct  :)

Comment: Yah.. I am trying to upvote, but I get an message "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of **15 reputation**, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.".  +1

Comment: that's the SO policy preventing the new users for spam voting but there is a tick right below the votes, tick it and it will mark the answer correct.