# Multiple delete in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm currently trying to do multiple deletion in Laravel 5.3. I'd like to be something just like how emails are deleted using checkbox.

[image: Something like this]

But before deleting, I'd like to do confirmation using a modal.

[image: Modal Confirmation]

form in my blade looks like this

```
<form id="linkForm" action="/links/deleteLinks" method="POST">    
                {{ csrf_field() }}        
                {{ method_field('POST') }}
            <div class="ibox-content">

            <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example footable toggle-arrow-tiny">  



                <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm pull-right">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary" href="#modal-form-add" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i> Add</a>
                    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">

                </div>

                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th data-toggle="true" data-hide="all">Company</th>
                    {{-- <th>Category</th>     --}}
                    <th>Page Url</th>
                    <th data-hide="all">Domain Url</th>
                    <th>Destination Url</th>
                    <th>Contact Email</th>
                    <th data-hide="all">Trust Flow</th>
                    <th data-hide="all">Estimated Traffic</th>
                    <th data-hide="all">Domain Authority</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Note</th>
                    <th data-hide="all">Live</th>
                    <th>Action</th>

                    {{-- <th>Delete</th> --}}
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>


                    @foreach($links as $link)
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" id="input" name="input[]"  value="{{ $link->page_url }}"></td>
                        <td>{{ $link->company->name }}</td> 
                        {{-- <td>{{ $link->category_id }}</td> --}}
                        <td>{{ $link->page_url }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $link->domain_url }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $link->destination_url }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $link->contact_email }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $link->trust_flow}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $link->estimated_traffic }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $link->domain_authority }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $link->status }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $link->comment }}</td>
                        <td>
                            @if($link->is_live)
                                {{ 'Live' }}
                            @else
                                {{ 'Down' }}
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-form-{{ $link->id }}" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>

                        </td>



                    </tr>

                    @endforeach
                 </tbody>
            </table>

            </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

modal.blade.php

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal inmodal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                 <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle modal-icon"></i>
                <h2><strong>Are you sure?</strong></h2>   

                {{-- <p class="text-muted">Are you sure you want to delete the following link(s)?</p> --}}


                <p id="checkid"></p>

                <div class="row">
                    <button id="cancelDelete" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                     <button class="btn-primary btn" id="SubForm">Confirm and Submit The Form</button>
                </div>

            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript

```
    $("#linkForm").validate({

    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
        $('#SubForm').click(function () {
            form.submit();
       });
    }
});
```

How can I submit my array to the controller without creating another function and route for multiple delete and just use links.destroy?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the array from the form like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="{{$row->id}}"/>
```

In your controller you can do

```
Model::whereIn('id', $request->ids)->destroy();
```

Comment: I think you mean `$request->ids`

Comment: Indeed my friend. Thanks

Comment: How can I pass the my array to my controller? I'm not really that familiar with js.

Comment: I am just using a simple form. that would do the job. JS intervenes on the modal only. So you should actually submit the form from the modal. But that is an entire different question from what you asked here. I think there are some ways like preventing default when the modal opens. and on modal close, submit the form. Please follow this link, they show exactly how to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666100/jquery-form-submit-with-bootstrap-modal-confirmation

Comment: @EddyTheDove i'm trying to implement your codes in my project now but the modal doesn't appear and there is an error that $(...).validate is not a function..

Comment: My code does not deal with the modal. Do you mean the link I gave you? It seems the error is  a javascript error.

Comment: Maybe update you original question with your JS code. And someone coul d pick what's not working.

Comment: ohh i see.. i misunderstood your comment.. i thought the link you sent was your solution.. my bad..

Answer (score 0):

You can always collect the links through JS and send them along. In the Laravel controller you'll simply add an if condition to differentiate between the two requests.

By the by, whether it is only one id or several, you should always make sure that permissions over them are enforced.

Elaborating on my answer,

Suppose you've got a collection of articles, each of which can be marked for deletion

```
<input type="checkbox" name="article[]" value="1" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="article[]" value="2" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="article[]" value="3" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="article[]" value="4">
```

Then you can collect those ids with

```
let ids = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="article[]"'))
               .filter(el => el.checked)
               .map(el => el.value);
```

And later on send them thorugh an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: how? i don't have much  knowledge when it comes to js

Comment: @GabrielLuna if you're placing the checkboxes within a form, then the answer by Eddy is actually the easiest and cleaner way to do it.

Comment: yes, i'm putting my checkboxes in a form and i'm currently trying out eddy's code.. but still no luck.. anyway, will explore yours and eddy's solution..